# Change linked tables in MS Access from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ms-access, linked-tables

We are in the process of migrating our SQL Server database to Oracle. Some business users have an Access DB with tables linked to SQL Server.  Is there a way to change these connections to Oracle, and if so, is there a way to do that so the queries do not have to be updated to reflect the new source?

One of the issues I'm running into is the name of the existing linked table is DBO_TABLE1 (SQL Server connection).  When I try to repoint that to Oracle, there is a different schema (let's call it SCHEMA1), so it doesn't recognize the name DBO_TABLE1.

It looks like I'd have to create new connections for each of the linked tables, which is going to be tedious because there are a lot of tables as well as many queries that will need to be modified to use the new table names.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will have to create new linked tables. And you are correct that is puts the schema as part of the name by default. You could always change the name but that would be really bizarre if the schema in oracle is different (which I assume it won't be dbo).

Comment: You could (but I wouldn't recommend it; it could cause confusion and maintenance headaches) create synonyms for the new objects in Oracle with the old names. I would create these as private synonyms for the user the access database logs in as, if I had to go down that route. Far better would be to update the Access DB to point to the newly named tables instead.